# Python C API: Assigning PyObjects to a dictionary causes memory leak

Tags: python, c++, memory-leaks, python-c-api

I am writing a C++ wrapper for Python using the Python C API. In my case I have to make bigger amounts of byte oriented data accessible for the Python script. For this purpose I use the `PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize` method  to produce a Python bytearray (https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/bytearray.html).

When returning this bytearray directly I have not experienced any problems. When however adding the bytearray into a Python dict, the memory from the bytearray will not be released once the dict is destroyed.

This can be solved by calling `Py_DECREF` on the bytearray object after adding the bytearray object to the Python dict.

Below is a complete working example of my code containing a method `dummyArrPlain` returning the plain bytearray and a method `dummyArrInDict` returning a bytearray in a dict. The second method will produce a memory leak unless `Py_DECREF(pyData);` is called.

**My question is:** Why is `Py_DECREF` necessary at this point. Intuitively I would have expected that `Py_DECREF` should be called once the dict is destroyed.

Also I assign values like in the following to a dict:

```
PyDict_SetItem(dict, PyString_FromString("i"), PyInt_FromLong(i));
```

Will this also produce a memory leak when not calling `Py_DECREF` on the created string and long?

This is my dummy C++ wrapper:

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

static char module_docstring[] = "This is a module causing a memory leak";

static PyObject *dummyArrPlain(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
static PyObject *dummyArrInDict(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    {"dummy_arr_plain", dummyArrPlain, METH_VARARGS, "returns a plain dummy bytearray"},
    {"dummy_arr_in_dict", dummyArrInDict, METH_VARARGS, "returns a dummy bytearray in a dict"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initlibdummy(void)
{
    PyObject *m = Py_InitModule("libdummy", module_methods);
    if (m == NULL)
        return;
}


static PyObject *dummyArrPlain(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int len = 10000000;
    char* data = new char[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        data[i] = 0;
    }

    PyObject * pyData = PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize(data, len);
    delete [] data;

    return pyData;
}


static PyObject *dummyArrInDict(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int len = 10000000;
    char* data = new char[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
    PyObject * pyData = PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize(data, len);
    delete [] data;

    PyObject *dict = PyDict_New();
    PyDict_SetItem(dict, PyString_FromString("data"), pyData);

    // memory leak without Py_DECREF(pyData);

    return dict;
}
```

And a dummy python script using the wrapper:

```
import libdummy
import time

while True:
    a = libdummy.dummy_arr_in_dict()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of [[Python 2.0.Docs]: Ownership rules](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ext/ownershipRules.html). I'm going to exemplify on *Python 2.7.10* (pretty old, but I don't think that the behavior has (significantly) changed along the way).

*PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize* (*bytearrayobject.c*: *168*) creates a new object (using *PyObject_New*, and allocates memory for the buffer as well).

By default, the *refcount* of that object (or better: of any newly created object) is **1** (set by *_Py_NewReference*), so that when the user calls *del* upon it, or at program exit, the *refcount* will be decreased, and when reaching 0, the object will be deallocated.

- This is the behavior on the flow where the object is returned
- But, in *dummyArrInDict*'s case, *PyDict_SetItem* does (indirectly) a *Py_INCREF* of *pyData* (it does other stuff, but only this is relevant in the current situation), ending up with a *refcount* of **2** and therefore the memory leak

It's basically same thing that you're doing with *data*: you allocate memory for it, and when you no longer need it, you free it (this is because you're not returning it, you only use it temporarily).

**Note**: It's safer to use the **X** macros (e.g. [[Python 2.Docs]: **Py_XDECREF**](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/refcounting.html#c.Py_XDECREF), especially since you're not testing for *NULL* the returned *PyObject*s).

For more details, also take a look at [[Python 2.Docs]: C API Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html).

Comment: Thanks, I also thought that this might be the problem. So this means when I set a value in a dict using `PyDict_SetItem(dict, PyString_FromString("version"), PyInt_FromLong(version));` I will end up with a string and a long with ref count of 2 also causing memory leaks?

Comment: Yes. Browsing *Python*'s  source code, you'll notice that every object created __locally__ (in order to be passed to `PyDict_SetItem`) is `Py_DECREF`ed (or its `Py_REFCNT` decremented) afterwards.